# Linux command for search substring

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find the word 'on' as a prefix or suffix of a string, but not where it is in the middle.

As an example,
I have a text which has words like 'on', 'one', 'cron', 'stone'. I want to find lines which contains exact word 'on' and also words like 'one' and 'cron', but it should not match stone.

Comment: Words *like* "one" and "cron", but not "stone". So... no sibilants? Abstract nouns only? Maybe you can use the `do-what-I-mean` flag.

Comment: Try using the command: grep

Comment: what is the rule for what should and should not be included.

Comment: Try this. egrep '(^on|on$)' fileName. Assuming you want words beginning and ending with 'on' but not where it is in the middle.

Comment: 'on' can be only a prefix or suffix

Comment: @SameerNaik: Your suggestion would only accept `on` at the beginning or end of the line; it would not accept words starting or ending 'on' in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got GNU `grep` or BSD `grep`, then it is relatively straight-forward:

```
grep -E '\b(on[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*on)\b'
```

This looks for a word boundary followed by 'on' and zero or more alphabetic characters, or for zero or more alphabetic characters followed by 'on', followed by a word boundary.

For example, given the data:

```
on line should be selected 
cron line should be selected
stone line should not be selected
station wagon 
onwards, ever onwards.
on24 is not selected
24on is not selected
```

Example run:

```
$ grep -E '\b(on[[:alpha:]]*|[[:alpha:]]*on)\b' data
on line should be selected
cron line should be selected
station wagon
onwards, ever onwards.
$
```

With a strict POSIX-compatible `grep`, you would have to work a lot harder, if it can be done at all.

Note that this solution is assuming that mixed digits and letters are not a 'word' in this context (so neither `on24` nor `24on` should be selected).  If you don't mind digits appearing as part of a word starting or ending 'on', then you can use either of two other answers:

- [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431664/15168)
- [alfasin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1057429/alfasin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431233/15168)

or you can hack this one into shape so it does what one of theirs does.

Comment: Note the solution by @tripleee — if the fact that it accepts `24on` and `on24` is OK, then use it because it is simpler (or mine can be reduced to being equivalent dropping the `[[:alpha:]]*` terms).

Comment: But this one does, too, because you have a zero or more quantifier on the `[[:alpha:]]` character class.  If you drop the quantifier, it will be more strict *and* more efficient.

Comment: @tripleee: No, this solution rejects `on24` and `24on` because the regex requires all alpha, but the word boundary operators accept 24 as part of the word (so there isn't a word boundary between `n` and `2`, nor between `4` and `o`).  Try it.  At least, on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with BSD `grep`, the regex shown omits lines containing either or both `on24` and `24on` when there's no other eligible 'on' word on the line.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I overlooked the grouping parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised nobody has proposed the simple, obvious

```
grep -E '\<on|on\>' files ...
```

The metacharacter sequences `\<` and `\>` match a left and right word boundary, respectively.  I believe it should be portable to any modern platform (though I would be unsurprised if Solaris, HP-UX, or AIX required some tweaks in order to get it to work).

Comment: Nice and simple.  It would, however, accept `on24` or `24on`; it isn't clearly defined whether that's OK or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use egrep (regex) in order to catch the exact phrases: by using `\b` (word boundary) you can make sure to not catch anything else other than the required 3 words:

```
egrep -e '\b(on|one|cron)\b' <filename>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since the question was edited & clarified that the OP is looking to have `on` "as a prefix or suffix of a string":

```
egrep -e '\bon|on\b' <filename>
```

Comment: Note that this answer was provided before the question was clarified.

Comment: YW: You might care to look at my comment to [triplee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32431664/15168).  It applies to your (current) update.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point. I assumed that if the sentence contains something like `on24` it will be considered as a valid "word" but indeed it might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going 'all out' and searching for anything with the substring 'on' in it (leaving out 'stone')...

```
grep '[A-Za-z]on[A-Za-z]' <your file name> | grep -v 'stone'
```

piping into the `grep` command again will hide any of the results that were 'stone'

Comment: 'on' can be only a prefix or suffix. but not where it is in the middle.

Comment: You should add that to your initial post because it isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Note that this answer was provided before the question was clarified.